# How can we decrypt all RSA messages given a function that can efficiently decrypt a small percentage of all possible ciphertexts?

Tags: encryption, rsa, decryption

I saw this question in a paper and was not able to solve it. Assume that we are given an efficient algorithm called `RSA_break()` that can decrypt, without the knowledge of the private key, 1% of all possible ciphertexts encrypted using the public key (n,e) in RSA. Basically, for a single ciphertext, `RSA_break()` will deterministically output the entire original plaintext or return a failure. For 1% of the set of all possible ciphertexts, `RSA_break()` always succeeds, while for the rest 99%, it will always fail. How can I use this `RSA_break()` function as a building block to build an efficient algorithm to break all possible ciphertexts?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the paper? And you can try all messages even in parallel but 1% is far from to reach. Remember that public key encryption is free and this is the NOT TO USE INSECURE RSA TEXTBOOK!

Comment: The paper mentioned is just a problem sheet on cryptography, no further context is provided for the task. Although I am sure that the solution needs to be mathematically derived from the number theory behind RSA.

Comment: Hint: Turn the task of deciphering a particular message into the task of deciphering any one of some hundreds truly random messages, something that the black box capable of undoing textbook RSA encryption for 1% or random messages will do with good probability. Note: It's our policy to only give hints to what looks like a homework question. These are off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) when stated without evidence of personal work.